# Where I find add_PropertyChanged() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a report viewer that I'd like to see when it has finished loading, to do that I can use the add_PropertyChanged() function, however the console spits out an error saying that the function is not found. 
What script am I missing?

> Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
>       $find(viewerID).add_propertyChanged(viewerPropertyChanged); });
>
> function viewerPropertyChanged(sender, e) {
>       if (e.get_propertyName() == "zoomLevel") {
>           var viewer = $find(viewerID);
>           if (!viewer.get_isLoading() && viewer.get_zoomLevel() < 20) {
>               viewer.set_zoomLevel(20);
>               alert("Reset zoomLevel to 20.");
>           }
>       } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add_propertyChanged()` function comes from the ASP.NET AJAX library.
I believe the element you are operating on has to be on your aspx page, so the `viewerID` you are passing in must be the ID of the rsweb ReportViewer on your aspx page.